# Texmaker error: "missing $ inserted"

Tags: math-mode, texmaker, missing

I get the following error in texmaker:
[image]
I have multiple files opened, but I since it doesn't show a file name I dont know where this error should occur. I also went through all my files and the bibliography and checked lines 53 and 55 without spotting any missing $. How do I know which file this error message is for?

This is the part of the logfile:

```
(09_diskussion.tex
chapter 6.
) [30
] (00_Vorlage Abschlussarbeit.bbl
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.53 centres{\ast
}.
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
l.53 centres{\ast}
.
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.55
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
}
l.55
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
```

Comment: if you look at the log you can see which file was last opened before the error

Comment: you should be looking for `\ast` not `$`

Comment: Search for centres{\ast in your files and check if there is an extra $ in the preceding text? By the way how is this question related to biblatex?

Comment: I looked for centres{\ast and had one entry in my bibliography, but there was no $ in the preceeding text. The discussion file is the last before my bibliography, so could the mistake occur in the bib file (regarding the log file)

Comment: @trynerror  `but there was no $ in the preceeding text.` that _is_ the error as `\ast` is  math -mode command.

Comment: I understand but I took the part the whole bib entry out of the file and still get the error, even though I can't find any centers {\ast in my files anymore. Sorry if I am misunderstanding something

Comment: you need to regenerate your bbl fle with bibtex (or biber if using biblatex) just fixing the .bib will not work

Comment: see the (badly formatted:-) error you just added, latex reports the error in `00_Vorlage Abschlussarbeit.bbl `  so it is that bbl file you need to fix

Comment: Thank you for the reformatting.. :). "00_Vorlage Abschlussarbeit" is my main file. I dont have a "00_Vorlage Abschlussarbeit.bbl" file to look at. I just have my library.bib file

Comment: Yes you do have that file, in the current directory, you made it by running bibtex previously (latex itself never reads the bib file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your main file is

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

aaaaaaa

\input{wibble}


\end{document}
```

and `wibble.tex` is

```
aa

centres{\ast i}

bbb
```

Then the error in the log is

```
(./wibble.tex
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.3 centres{\ast
                 i}
?
```

Note the log file is almost always more informative than the "summary" that may be provided by your editor.

Here `(./wibble.tex` logs `wibble.tex` being opened, and as there is no matching `)` that file is still open at the point of the error, so `l.3` refers to line 3 of `wibble`. As confirmed by the line of context shown.

The actual error is that `\ast` is a math command, I'm not sure what expression you intended but changing `wibble.tex` as below fixes the error

```
aa

centres $\ast i$

bbb
```

Answer (score 3):

The input `centres{\ast}` is an error, because `\ast` is a math mode command. So upon finding it,

1. TeX adds a `$` by itself (first error message).
2. Then TeX finds `}` which would lead to unbalanced lists: it would be as if you typed `centres{$\ast}...` which is illegal (second error message).
3. At line 55 TeX is likely finding a blank line; since math mode has started but is not finished, a `$` is added (third error message).
4. But upon closing math mode, there is still the `{` after `centres` that remains unbalanced (fourth error message), because the `}` that was found before has been removed as part of error recovering in step 2.

The wrong input is in the `.bbl` file which is generated by BibTeX. You know this because of

```
chapter 6.
) [30
] (00_Vorlage Abschlussarbeit.bbl
! Missing $ inserted.
```

which tells you that TeX is reading from `00_Vorlage Abschlussarbeit.bbl` (by the way, avoid spaces in names of LaTeX files).

BibTeX knows very little of TeX. If your `.bib` file has `centres{\ast}`, then BibTeX will do nothing to it.

It's possible that “smart” bibliography managers such as Mendeley, try to be even smarter and change `centres*` into `centres{\ast}` or something similar.

Fix the entry in the bib file and rerun BibTeX (or Biber, depending on whether you're using `biblatex`).

Comment: the problem is centres{\ast} or \ast doesn't even show up in my bibfile. So I dont know what to change since I am not using Mendeley.

Comment: @trynerror You can open the `.bbl` file and look what bibliography item line 53 is about. Then you can look for it in the bib file and fix the wrong input.

Comment: Ok in the bbl file in line 53 there is centres{\ast}. It was the entry I already suspected, thats why I completely deleted him out of my bib file to see if it works. Should I also delete it in the bbl file ?

Comment: ok it is working now thank you very much for your efforts!